# Update in ListView Renderer

Tags: android, forms, listview, xamarin, renderer

I need update item data in native `ListView`.

**1. Using Xamarin.Forms ListView.** Simple `DataItem` model with `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
    List<DataItem> Data = new List<DataItem>();
    // ... fill Data
    ListView listDevice = new ListView();
    listDevice.ItemsSource = Data;
    listDevice.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataView));
    ...
    void BtnTest_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Data[0].DeviceName = "Update OK";
    }
```

When btnTest clicked I see "Update OK" in first ListView element immediately. Everything fine.

**2. Using Renderer for ListView.** Im using [WorkingWithListviewNative](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithListviewNative/WorkingWithListviewNative/D) example, its has renderer and adapter. Im replace `DataSource2` to `DataItem` model(everywhere) and add same btnTest. List with data is visible, but when button clicked nothing changes. I see changes after scroll down and up.

Which code do I need to add to renderer (to OnElementPropertyChanged?) or to  the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of List use ObservableCollection and you don't need to do a property change notification as it handles it.

Comment: ObservableCollection update ListView(in first example) only when using Add, Remove, Insert and not on direct edit (Data[0].ItemName = "..."). In this way you need use dirty hack(save item, remove it form DataSource, edit saved item, insert saved item in DataSource) Anyway, ObservableCollection doesn't work in second example(with custom renderer). I think some magic code must be added to renderer or adapter.

Comment: I assume you can implement INotifyCollectionChanged on your own class, but I haven't done it.